# Radio button in controller scope are not working in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have form where i want to submit the whole data everything is fine except the radio button. The problem occurs when the radio buttons are in controller scope but they work fine out of controller scope. i am getting all other fields value properly except the radio button and i dont know where i am making mistake i am confuse why its not working...

Here is the angular script which is working fine...

```
//handling form controller
     app.controller('myForm',function($http,$scope){
        $scope.formData={};
        $scope.saveCashbook=function()
        {
            console.log(this.formData);
          $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: 'cashbook/save_cash_entry',
            data: $.param($scope.formData),
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
          }).success(function (data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
              alert('all okay');
            } else {
              alert(data)
            }
          });
        }

     });
```

Here is my html in which two way data-binding isnt working while the radio buttons are in scope and when i placed them out from controller scope two way data binding start working but than i wont be able to get my radio button value in my controller where i am saving them to database.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-controller="myForm">

                            <form name="supplier_form" id="myform" ng-submit="saveCashbook()" >
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-2" style="padding-top:30px;">
                                        <label for="" class="label label-info">جمع</label>
                                         <label class="control-label radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" class="purple" value="jama" name="jamabanam" ng-model="formData.jamabanam" >

                                    </label>
                                    <label for="" class="label label-danger">بنام</label>
                                    <label class="control-label radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" class="purple" value="banam" name="jamabanam" ng-model="formData.jamabanam" > 
                                    </label>
                                    </div>  

                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                                        <label for="packing" class="control-label">رجسٹر</label>
                                        <select id="register" name="register_id" ng-model="formData.register_id" class="form-control search-select two" >
                                                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                                    <? $query=$this->dba->get_dropdown('register',array('id','name'));

                                                        foreach($query as $key=>$value):
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="<?=$key?>"><?=$value; ?></option>
                                                <? endforeach;?>
                                                </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="raqam" class="control-label">نام</label>
                                        <select id="name" name="name" ng-model="formData.name" class="form-control search-select two"></select>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-2 has-error">
                                        <label for="nuqsani-raqam" class="control-label">کھاتہ نمبر</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="khata_id" ng-model="formData.khata_id" id="khata_no" >
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-2 has-success">
                                        <label for="nuqsani-raqam" class="control-label">رقم</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="raqam" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.raqam" id="raqqam"> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                        <label for="raqam" class="control-label">تفصیل</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="details" ng-model="formData.details" id="details" class="form-control" >
                                    </div>

                                    <input type="submit" value="submit"  name="submit" id="submit">
                            </form>

                        </div>
```

**Here is my php function where i am priniting the whole `$_POST`**

```
public function save_cash_entry()
    {
        print_r($_POST);
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: i tried your code, i am getting the value of radio button in console from this like, console.log(this.formData); and in the form radio buttons are in the controller.
or i didn't understand your problem?

Comment: but i am doing the same i am not getting any value and at last i serialize the whole array to overcome this problem but i didnt get any value i dont know why i tried every possible way